# How to overwrite checkpoint of same global step for Tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

If you resume training from a specific epoch (same global step) and run tensorboard, tensorboard (add_scalar) will end up plotting 2 points for that particular global step.

Example, I want trying to test whether changing the learning rate halfway through training will improve/worsen the accuracy:

[Plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViZ0T.png)

The plots for same time step are plotted twice (I resumed from +15 epochs behind the latest epoch).

Search up the web, cannot find any commands that can ask Tensorboard to just overwrite the previous saved checkpoint for the new one. My expectation is that Tensorboard would know to overwrite the same global step point but it is plotting it together.

Comment: When you restart an experiment, tensorboard creates a new event file. And when you run tensorboard to display it, it simply loads data from the 2 files (the old experiment and the new experiment that you started with -15 epochs) without considering any overlaps. You might have to open an issue on the Tensorboard github repo itself.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering whether can the event files not overlay on the same global step, it make sense that it is doable.  I think it's pretty common for DL practitioner to use an old epoch to do some experiments, surprised that Tensorboard won't support it. I will wait for a few days before raising the issue to Tensorboard in case someone has a workaround/solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the log file running the script (before creating model).
And then it will be created empty.
Or you can add time in the name of the log:

```
import time
NAME = 'my_cnn-{}'.format(int(time.time()))
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))
```